# assetmanager.aspx is compromised

Tags: asp.net, security

The very old website running asp.net the backend ADMIN content system uses a WYSIWYG Editor

```
<editor:WYSIWYGEditor ID="txtBio"
    runat="server"
    scriptPath="../../WYSIWYG/scripts/"
    Width="100%"
    AssetManager="../../WYSIWYG/assetmanager/assetmanager.aspx"
    AssetManagerHeight="550"
    AssetManagerWidth="570">
</editor:WYSIWYGEditor>
```

The attacker Brute-forced the path of this script and then posted requests to the script directly, therefore was able to execute upload commands...

The assetmanager I can't update this software to hope that the new version is loophole-free (it cost money to use that product...)

I really do not whant to remove this everywhere on the CMS since it is all coded into each section...

My question is - `in asp.net can I find the requester of the POST's requesting source to determine if this post request is coming from the admin pages or just outside` and would I also need to attach the user log in session check for the upload portion of the function?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on which scripts are compromised? Server side? If yes, is there any authentication/authorization? Client side? Then how the attacker can compromise anything at the server?

Comment: The `assetmanager.aspx` has NO authentication but it is only called in the backend, the backend has a authentication on all cms pages. the attack was able to directly post data to the script.

Comment: then why `assetmanager.aspx` has NO authentication? It should have.

Comment: Exactly. Authentication is the answer to this question. No attacker would be able to do anything as simple as what you describe.